# Have divs fall into place as surrounding divs disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JavaScript that as you type into an input box, it looks through the IDs for a string match from the input, and if at some point the string doesn't match, that specific div will be set to display none. Everything was going good, except here is an example of my markup:

```
<div id="veryOuterContainer">
<div id="rowOfDivs">
    <div class="pics" id="BusterPosey"><p>This is a first test of the search</p></div>
    <div class="pics" id="FrankGore"><p>This is a second test of the search</p></div>
    <div class="pics" id="BrandonBelt"><p>This is a third test of the search</p></div>
    <div class="pics" id="DraymondGreen"><p>This is a fourth test of the search</p></div>
    <div class="pics" id="NavarroBowman"><p>This is a fifth test of the search</p></div>
</div>
<div id="rowOfDivs">
    <div class="pics" id="BusterPosey"><p>This is a first test of the search</p></div>
    <div class="pics" id="FrankGore"><p>This is a second test of the search</p></div>
    <div class="pics" id="BrandonBelt"><p>This is a third test of the search</p></div>
    <div class="pics" id="DraymondGreen"><p>This is a fourth test of the search</p></div>
    <div class="pics" id="NavarroBowman"><p>This is a fifth test of the search</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I can get the divs to disappear just fine, and they stay all nice and styled....but they stay on the same line they started. For instance, if I had a string match for "BusterPosey", it would look like this:

```
This is a first test of the search
This is a first test of the search
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
This is a first test of the search This is a first test of the search
```

And I just can't figure out how to get the individual divs in different rows to align on the same line (and then wrap when the max-width was reached).
I have tried the following:

```
#veryOuterContainer {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This did nothing.
I have also tried:

```
#veryOuterContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

And:

```
#veryOuterContainer {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Both of those rendered every matched individual div on the same line, and I'm dealing with about 150 divs, so as you can imagine, they were so scrunched together making it impossible to make out any of them.

Comment: You will have to not wrap them in different divs.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why its not showing up in rows is because you need to have the other bottom parent be a display of flex because it controls its children elements. Example below:

```
#veryOuterContainer #rowOfDivs {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I made a typo in retyping my code, fixed it above

Comment: I see your problem. You need to do display flex on `#rowOfDivs` as well.